# UINavigationItem does not show activity indicator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

My application has a `UITabBarController`. When the first view loads I start a new thread from its

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

method, which runs a task. When the task starts, it calls a delegate method from the first view and adds an activity indicator to the `UINavigationItem`. When it ends, it calls another delegate method from the first view, and hides activity indicator.

The problem is that the activity indicator is not shown, unless I go to another view and then back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to guess what is happening. In the past, UIKit methods have not been thread-safe and were required to be called on the main thread. It seems like a long shot in this scenario, but have you ruled this out?

Comment: This is exactly what was the problem. Doing [self performSelectorOnMainThread...] solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?